# Scrot screenshot shell script not working inside crontab

Tags: shell, cron

I am working on a script to take screenshot every 10 minutes using `scrot` and `crontab` for repeating.

My code is

```
folder=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")

mkdir -p ~/.hostlog/$folder
sh ~/.hostlog/hostlog.sh >> ~/.hostlog/$folder/$(date +%H-%M-%S).txt &
scrot ~/.hostlog/$folder/$(date +%H-%M-%S).jpg &
```

When I run this script on terminal, I am able to get a screenshot. But when I add it to `crontab`. I do not get any screenshot. But I get the text file for this.

```
sh ~/.hostlog/hostlog.sh >> ~/.hostlog/$folder/$(date +%H-%M-%S).txt &
```

I did not get the output for this.

```
scrot ~/.hostlog/$folder/$(date +%H-%M-%S).jpg &
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the DISPLAY environment variable when running the scrot command:

`DISPLAY=:0 scrot ~/.hostlog/$folder/$(date +%H-%M-%S)`